# How to FOR and IF loop in R to sum values according to two factor levels and create new variable?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, dplyr

I want my data frame to be like

```
> trial_acc
   df$Condition df$id df$correct keep
1            1_1 006          1   no
2            3_3 006          1   no
3            1_3 006          5   no
4            3_1 006          3   no
5            1_1 0ui         13   yes
6            3_3 0ui         18   yes
7            1_3 0ui         16   yes
8            3_1 0ui         13   yes
9            1_1 12f         12   no
10           3_3 12f          2   no
11           1_3 12f         13   no
12           3_1 12f          7   no
```

I need to create a variable 'keep' where "yes" if the total of df$correct is >= 40 grouped by df$id, otherwise "no"

I tried this but it is not working

```
for (i in levels(trial_acc$`df$id`)) {
  if (trial_acc$`df$id` == i & sum(trial_acc$`df$correct`) >=  40){
    trial_acc$keep <- "yes"
  } else{
    trial_acc$keep <- "no"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer the `dplyr`, you can do this: (I am using the data and simplified columns by @mt1022)

```
trail_acc%>%group_by(id)%>%
  mutate(keep = ifelse(sum(correct) >= 40, 'yes', 'no'))%>%
  ungroup()

    # A tibble: 12 x 4
   Condition id    correct keep 
   <fct>     <fct>   <int> <chr>
 1 1_1       006         1 no   
 2 3_3       006         1 no   
 3 1_3       006         5 no   
 4 3_1       006         3 no   
 5 1_1       0ui        13 yes  
 6 3_3       0ui        18 yes  
 7 1_3       0ui        16 yes  
 8 3_1       0ui        13 yes  
 9 1_1       12f        12 no   
10 3_3       12f         2 no   
11 1_3       12f        13 no   
12 3_1       12f         7 no
```

Answer (score 0):

By `trail_acc$keep <- "yes"` or `"no"`, you were changing the value of the whole column. To change only the values of the affected rows, I would use the following way:

```
trail_acc$keep <- 'no'  # set default to "no"
for(i in unique(trail_acc$id)){
    if(sum(trail_acc$correct[trail_acc$id == i]) >= 40){
        trail_acc$keep[trail_acc$id == i] <- 'yes'
    }
}
```

You can also do it in a vectorized way with `ave` and `ifelse`:

```
sum_by_id <- ave(trail_acc$correct, trail_acc$id, FUN = sum)
trail_acc$keep <- ifelse(sum_by_id >= 40, 'yes', 'no')

#    Condition  id correct keep
# 1        1_1 006       1   no
# 2        3_3 006       1   no
# 3        1_3 006       5   no
# 4        3_1 006       3   no
# 5        1_1 0ui      13  yes
# 6        3_3 0ui      18  yes
# 7        1_3 0ui      16  yes
# 8        3_1 0ui      13  yes
# 9        1_1 12f      12   no
# 10       3_3 12f       2   no
# 11       1_3 12f      13   no
# 12       3_1 12f       7   no
```

Note I used a `trail_acc` with simplified column names:

```
trail_acc <- structure(list(Condition = structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1_1", "1_3", "3_1", "3_3"
), class = "factor"), id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("006", "0ui", "12f"), class = "factor"), 
    correct = c(1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 13L, 18L, 16L, 13L, 12L, 2L, 
    13L, 7L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "data.frame")
```